# MySQL Table order is correct, data types match, so why do I get ERROR 1005 (HY000)

Tags: mysql, database

I have several tables and several of them reference each other to create many-to-many relationships.  I realize data types must match and table order matters when creating the foreign keys.  I think I have all that accounted for.  So why am I getting the ERROR 1005 (HY000) in the following:

```
CREATE TABLE USER (
id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL auto_increment PRIMARY KEY,
userName VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
email VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
firstName VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
lastName VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
salt CHAR(10) NOT NULL,
HASH CHAR(40)
)ENGINE=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE PRODUCT (
id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL auto_increment PRIMARY KEY,
prodName VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
price DECIMAL(6,2),
availability BOOLEAN,
description VARCHAR(150) NOT NULL,
size VARCHAR(20),
weight VARCHAR(10)
)ENGINE=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE USERENTERSPRODUCT (
userID INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
prodID INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (userID, prodID),
FOREIGN KEY (userID) REFERENCES USER(id) ON DELETE SET NULL ON UPDATE CASCADE,
FOREIGN KEY (prodID) REFERENCES PRODUCT(id) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
)ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Comment: You're getting the error with the create statements or running a query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE USERENTERSPRODUCT (
  userID INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  prodID INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (userID, prodID),
  FOREIGN KEY (userID) REFERENCES USER(id) ON DELETE SET NULL ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  FOREIGN KEY (prodID) REFERENCES PRODUCT(id) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
)ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

You are specifying `ON DELETE SET NULL` here, but at the same time both columns have `NOT NULL` specified as well … that obviously can’t work.

So either remove the `NOT NULL` from the column definition, or change `ON DELETE SET NULL` to whatever matches you needs best. (Normally that should be `CASCADE` as well, that makes the most sense.)

Comment: Of course, how stupid of me....I'll get rid of the NOT NULL's.  That's what happens when I think about parts and not the whole.  Thank you!

Comment: _“I'll get rid of the NOT NULL's”_ – then you’ll get a NULL|NULL record in your `USERENTERSPRODUCT` table every time a user or product is removed from one of the two parent tables. Are you sure that `ON DELETE CASCADE` would not be the better option? Such a NULL|NULL record can hardly be of any further use, right?

Comment: Thank you, you are right.  I just wanted to maintain the record when the user is deleted, but it would not matter when the product is deleted.  But after further thought I realized both can cascade through.  So I can follow the course you recommend.  Now am I stuck on another table where this is an issue.  I'm just trying to figure it out now.  I've tried setting a default so we can ON DELETE SET DEFAULT but that isn't working either.  still thinking....

Comment: I just realized that this other relationship should be set-up as a one-to-many instead of a many-to-many.  That definitely makes a difference.